# How does express acts when it receives multiple same asynchronous requests from same source?

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous

I am using express js, I have an asynchronous function that takes about 20 - 30 seconds to make some work. After it makes that work it increments a counter for the user in the db. The user must wait at least 24 hours before making an other request.
My function checks the last time the counter of the user incremented before starting the work that takes about 30 secs. It only works if last update in the db is made before more than 24 hours.
What if a user sends multiple requests at once in a very short time (say send 5 requests in the same second), will the function start the work 5 times and increment his counter 5 times as a result (because when it checks for last update during that time it will find it happened more than 24 as the update of all the requests sent at same seconds is not written in the db yet) ? or it will only process requests one by one and will not process a second request until the first one returns a response and ends ? How can I prevent that problem from happening ?

**I want the api to process asynchronous requests from the same user ONE by ONE.**

Comment: Would it be valid behavior for your program to (1) check the state of the counter (2) increment it (3) _then_ complete the "work that takes ~30s"?

Comment: Does the request handler only start (trigger) the asynchronous function, or does it also wait for it to complete and send the http response only after the work is finished?

Comment: @jsejcksn , no the counter will update according to the result of the work that will be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the function start the work 5 times and increment his counter 5 times as a result?

Yes.

> Or will it only process requests one by one and will not process a second request until the first one returns a response and ends?

No, nodejs is designed to be asynchronous, handling multiple requests at the same time (assuming the request handler is asynchronous itself, like in your case).

> How can I prevent that problem from happening?

Check and increment the counter *before* doing the work.

Also, make that check-and-update an atomic transaction inside your database, so that there are absolutely no race conditions between multiple requests. Otherwise you still would run into issues with multiple checks happening before the updates, you only made them less likely by reducing the time window from around 30 seconds to a few milliseconds.

> I want the API to process asynchronous requests from the same user ONE by ONE.

You could do that by introducing a queue for each user. However, that will make horizontal scaling harder and also it's not exactly a good practice to wait many seconds before responding to a request, that'll likely cause a timeout on the client. Instead I would recommend responding immediately with a 409 (Conflict) or 429 (Too many request) HTTP status code while another request is already being processed, and make sure in the *client* logic that requests are only sent one after the other.

Comment: Have you considered that successful completion of the "~30s work" is a condition for incrementing the counter? [I asked the OP about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73182753/how-does-express-acts-when-it-receives-multiple-same-asynchronous-requests-from#comment129249957_73182753)

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't see how it could be, if the counter is meant to prevent *starting* the work

Comment: It seems clear (to me, at least) that some mutation/side-effect is what's trying to be rate-limited to 24 hrs, and that a retry should be allowed if the work that produces that mutation/side-effect fails.

Comment: @jsejcksn Hm, that might be possible, yeah… In that case I would recommend serialisable transactions in the database, and rollback the counter increment if the work fails.

Comment: that work itself like the counter must only be launched once per 24h, so I am afraid that if someone makes many requests in same second and the server starts processing them (because updating the counter may take some time too) ... isn't there any way to prevent processing requests that have same parameters at the same time ? like blocking all coming requests with same params if there is already a request with same params processing .. or something like that .

Comment: @Miracles "*because updating the counter may take some time too*" - that's why I said to use a transaction in the database. Databases are specifically built to offer such [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), use it! Of course there are ways to implement this yourself, but it's more error-prone and will fail as soon as you scale to multiple servers handling requests…

Comment: @Miracles If you need help implementing this, I would suggest [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you post details about which database system you are using and show the code with the database queries that check/update the counter